# Keep centered elements in same place regardless of scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I keep all of the elements on my website, [doggo.info](http://doggo.info) centered, but when the scrollbar is shown or hidden (seen by pressing the menu button on the top navigation) the elements jitter a few pixels left and right because of the difference in screen width made by the scrollbar.

Is there any HTML, CSS, or Javascript way to negate this? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you setting overflow:hidden on body element on click of menu?
I tried removing overflow:hidden from your 'toggleNav' function and it worked fine (no jittering happens)

Comment: I'm using overflow:hidden because I don't want the user to be able to scroll while the nav menu is open. Is there a way to disable scrolling without removing the scrollbard?

Comment: scrollbar*. Apparently I can't edit my comment :/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?
I am not exactly sure if you want this.

```
function toggleNav() {
  if (navopen) {
    document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "0";
    $("body").css({
       "position" : "relative",
       "overflow" : "scroll"
    });
    $("header").css("background-color","rgba(7,7,7,0.7)");
    navopen = false;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "200px";
    $("body").css({
       "position" : "fixed",
       "overflow" : "scroll"
    });
    $("header").css("background-color","rgba(7,7,7,1)");
    navopen = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it works great if I add `body {width: 100%;}` to my CSS, except it scrolls to the top of the page every time you open the navigation. Is there any way to avoid the scrolling to top?

Comment: You should mention your all scenarios in single question only. It is not possible to change solution with every new scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?